# Balance Error: Can not login with passed AccountID and PassPhrase or API is disabled on this account/IP in PerfectMoney API Integration python

Tags: python, api, authentication, payment

I am integrating Perfect Money on a project for Instant Payments. I am facing the errors here. I am applying all the information correctly but still its returning that the username and password supplied is incorrect. Here is my code.

```
from flask import *
from perfectmoney import PerfectMoney
login_id='xxxxxxx'
p_password='xxxxxxx'
def get_balance(account, password):
    pm = PerfectMoney(account, password)
    res = pm.balance()
    if pm.error:
        print(pm.error)
        return
    print (res)
@app.route("/account",methods=['GET','POST'])    
def account():
    get_balance(login_id,p_password)
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=TRUE)
```

I'm getting this Error - Can not login with passed AccountID and PassPhrase or API is disabled on this account/IP

Answer (score 2):

Today, I have just got the same issue like you.

Try to edit the IP Mask on PM API setting and the problem is fixed.

Comment: What is the IP address you've changed to? I asked the PM support and they told me that I have to use my server IP address as the IP mask but I still see the same issue.

Comment: If you want to allow all IP you could try this IP mask: "*(star).*(star).*(star).*(star)"

Answer (score 1):

you have to mask you server IP from your PM dashboard and make sure that API is activated in your account.

you have to use your login account ID as AccountID, and the passpharse you shouldn't use your real login password, you have to generate alternative passpharse from the settings page in your account and it is done and fix.

:)